# Searching MySQL database from tablename where column1 or column2 like term

Tags: mysql

I am searching my database for a specific name from columns.

Currently I can search only 1 column and I would like to search two.

This is my current statement:

```
$rs = mysql_query('select reg, make, model from Vehicles where reg like "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%" order by reg asc limit 0,10');
```

As you can see im searching for the registry name of the Vehicle and I get results of its model or make. **I would like to search for the Registry number or the make**. I tried:

```
$rs = mysql_query('select reg, make, model from Vehicles where reg, make like "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%" order by reg asc limit 0,10');
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `OR` if you have multiple condition.

```
select reg, make, model 
from Vehicles 
where reg like '%value%' OR
      make like '%value%'
order by reg asc 
limit 0,10
```

Comment: Like this: $rs = mysql_query('select reg, make, model from Vehicles where reg like "'. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%" OR make like '. mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) .'%" order by reg asc limit 0,10');

Cause the term would be the same

Comment: I dont get any results, either way.

Comment: try this by interchanging double quote with single quote. `$rs = mysql_query("
select reg, make, model 
from Vehicles 
where reg like '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) . "%' OR 
      make like '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']) . "%' 
   order by reg asc limit 0,10");`

Comment: ye that was the problem. Thank you